# Generating random numbers in excel (with set parameters and fixed cells)

Tags: excel, random, numbers, multiple-columns

I'm looking to assign random numbers to an excel sheet...see below

[image]

Here, the total determined is 3. This means I want to randomly add 3 to the rows in the CS-U column. This could be 1, 1, 1, in three random rows; a 2, and a 1 in two random rows or a 3 in one random row..etc..you get the picture. Is this possible in excel?

imgur link imgur.com/nflaS5F

Thanks for any tips/advice.

Comment: I think you'd need VBA to do this. The problem is separable into two parts. In the first part, you choose one of the outcomes 003, 012, 111 with a certain probability. In the second part, you assign the outcome vector to your data grid, using a different random process.

Comment: with extreme long formulas, it is possible... however, it will change at each calculation... you may need to go the VBA-way... but to simply answer your question: Yes :) (i assume you want random numbers in the set range with the sum of you set total, am i right?)

Comment: Hi, I will determine the number that is in the 'Total' column. So that number is not randomised.

Comment: Cant you use solver?

Comment: but having just a total leaves lots of possible values for your list (just the sum is set)... doing it random, will change the list at every calculation (while the sum stays the same)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this: (asuming the numbers are in `B2:B26` and total in `B27`)

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim Arr(1 To 25) As Long, iRnd As Long, i As Long
  'For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
  '  Arr(i) = 0
  'Next
  For i = 1 To [B27].Value
    Randomize
    iRnd = Int((25) * Rnd + 1)
    Arr(iRnd) = Arr(iRnd) + 1
  Next
  [B2:B26].Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr)
End Sub
```

It randomly selects 1 item and adds 1. Repeating for the set amound (in total `B27`)
pls add the 3 lines starting with `'` (but without the `'`) and check if the problem still occours

Comment: Is there a way to make this line "For i = 1 To Range("B27").Value" set to just the value in B27. Sometimes it generates a SUM that is greater than the total..for example see here...http://imgur.com/Y4JMU9q the number I put in is 4, but the total in column B is 8. Any Ideas?

Comment: `Range("B27").Value` is the cell where your total is set... in your image it would be `Range("B34").Value`

Comment: Yes, but the total in that column does not add up to 4? Any ideas?